# Recursion with code after the recursive call

Tags: recursion

I am trying to understand how recursion works and there is just one more thing that I do not quite understand: how a recursive function works when there is code *after* the recursive call within the recursive function itself. Please see below at the example pseudocode to help see what I mean. **My exact question is in what order (meaning when) the code after that recursive call will be executed.** *Will the machine note the recursive call, execute the remaining bit of code after the call (print "done"), then go back and actually execute the entire recursive call, or will the machine execute the recursive call as soon as it gets to that line and only execute that last bit of code (print "done") after that recursion bottoms out?*  **When** and how many times will "done" be printed?

```
void recurse()
{
  print "hello world";
  for i = 0 up to 2
    recurse();

  print "done";
}
```

Comment: The compiler, etc. don't make any exceptions to the normal rules for order of code execution when there's a recursive call. Things run in the same order as if `recurse()` was some other function entirely.

Comment: so what does this mean in terms of when and how many times "done" will be printed? Please help me understand this! I am new to recursion!

Comment: Since the recursion in this example is infinite, "done" _never_ gets printed. (Probably not what you intended.)

Comment: @usercow Did you try this out in any language? Your function doesn't have a _terminating condition_, that means it will never stop. Each call to `recurse()` will invoke two more calls, so the number of times it prints `"hello world"` will grow exponentially and is theoretically infinite. In reality, it will eventually run out of stack space and crash before the `"done"` appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to visualize recursion is using the depth/height of the stack. As you may know, whenever a new function is called, it's pushed onto the stack like a pancake, increasing the depth/height by 1. If you code it up and print your "start" and "end" notes with an indentation to visualize the depth, it should be easy to see what is executed when. In case it isn't clear, time is on the Y-axis (things printed above have executed before things below) and recursion depth is on the X-axis.

Here's the code in Python:

```
def recurse(depth=0):
    if depth < 4:
        print("    " * depth + f"starting at depth {depth}")

        for _ in range(2):
            recurse(depth + 1)

        print("    " * depth + f"ending at depth {depth}")

recurse()
```

Output:

```
starting at depth 0
    starting at depth 1
        starting at depth 2
            starting at depth 3
            ending at depth 3
            starting at depth 3
            ending at depth 3
        ending at depth 2
        starting at depth 2
            starting at depth 3
            ending at depth 3
            starting at depth 3
            ending at depth 3
        ending at depth 2
    ending at depth 1
    starting at depth 1
        starting at depth 2
            starting at depth 3
            ending at depth 3
            starting at depth 3
            ending at depth 3
        ending at depth 2
        starting at depth 2
            starting at depth 3
            ending at depth 3
            starting at depth 3
            ending at depth 3
        ending at depth 2
    ending at depth 1
ending at depth 0
```

As can be seen, there are two identical recursive calls that are spawned in the loop. The first trip through the loop completes its entire recursive execution before the second one begins. After both recursive calls complete, then the entire call ends.

Also note that the depth represents a [base case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_case_(recursion)) or terminal/leaf node that has no children. Your original algorithm will recurse infinitely and blow the stack.

Answer (score 6):

The recursive call runs BEFORE any code below it.  Once it returns, it will go back and finish the rest of the code.  So what happens is

```
"hello world"
i = 0
"hello world"
i = 0
"hello world"
...
```

forever.  Because you don't pass the value of `i` to the next recursive function, your code will run forever, restarting each time with `i=0`.

Let's assume though that you did pass `i` to the recursive function properly:

```
void recurse(i) {
    // is i still < 2?
    if (i < 2) {
        print "hello world";
        recurse(i+1);
        print "done";
    }

recurse(0);
```

In this case, you would get:

```
i = 0
"hello world"
    i = 1
    "hello world"
        i = 2
    "done"
"done"
```